# KeyBindings not responding in Swing App

Tags: java, eclipse, swing, user-interface, key-bindings

So i'm trying to write this app that's basically a game of who can press the keys faster( 1 for player 1 and 0 for player 2). The app has a simple GUI with a simple scoreboard that should be updated when the players hit one of the keys. 
Here's a screenshot of the GUI : http://screencloud.net/v/a6vT
Nevermind the start button, it's simply to reset the scores, i'll implement it later.

Here are the code files :

1.GameFrame.java

```
package MediatorGame;
import javax.swing.JFrame;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GameFrame extends JFrame {

    private GamePanel currentPanel; 

    public GameFrame() {

        currentPanel = new GamePanel();
        setupFrame();
    }

    private void setupFrame(){
        this.setContentPane(currentPanel);
        currentPanel.setFocusable(true);
        currentPanel.requestFocusInWindow();
        this.setSize(450, 300);
    }

}
```

2.GamePanel.java

```
package MediatorGame;

import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;



@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class GamePanel extends JPanel{
    private JButton startButton;
    private SpringLayout currentLayout;
    private JLabel p1Label;
    private JLabel p2Label;
    private int p1Score = 0;
    private int p2Score = 0;
    private JLabel p1ScoreLabel;
    private JLabel p2ScoreLabel;
    private InputMap iMap;
    private ActionMap aMap;


    public GamePanel() {
        startButton = new JButton("Start");
        currentLayout = new SpringLayout();
        p1Label = new JLabel("Player 1");
        p2Label = new JLabel("Player 2");
        p1ScoreLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(p1Score));
        p2ScoreLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(p2Score));
        iMap = getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);
        aMap = getActionMap();

        setupPanel();
    }

    private void setupPanel(){  
        setBackground(new Color(255, 255, 204));
        setLayout(currentLayout);           

        currentLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, startButton, 206, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
        currentLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.SOUTH, startButton, -40, SpringLayout.SOUTH, this);
        add(startButton);

        currentLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, p2Label, 50, SpringLayout.NORTH, this);
        currentLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.EAST, p2Label, -62, SpringLayout.EAST, this);
        add(p2Label);

        currentLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, p1Label, 75, SpringLayout.WEST, this);
        currentLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, p1Label, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, p2Label);
        add(p1Label);

        currentLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, p1ScoreLabel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, p1Label);
        currentLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, p1ScoreLabel, 0, SpringLayout.NORTH, p2ScoreLabel);
        add(p1ScoreLabel);

        currentLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.NORTH, p2ScoreLabel, 6, SpringLayout.SOUTH, p2Label);
        currentLayout.putConstraint(SpringLayout.WEST, p2ScoreLabel, 0, SpringLayout.WEST, p2Label);
        add(p2ScoreLabel);

        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_1, 0), "incP1Score");
        iMap.put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_0, 0), "incP2Score");
        aMap.put("incP1Score", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                p1Score += 1;
            }
        });
        aMap.put("incP2Score", new AbstractAction() {
            @Override
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
                p2Score += 1;
            }
        });

     }  
}
```

3.GUIRunner.java

```
package MediatorGame;

import javax.swing.UIManager;

public class GUIRunner {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            UIManager.setLookAndFeel(
            UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
        } catch(Exception e){ }

        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable(){
              public void run() {
                   GameFrame myApp = new GameFrame();
                   myApp.setVisible(true);
              }
        });
    }

}
```

I've checked a lot of questions. Most of them laid the blame on having the `JPanel` focusable, and asking for focus, wrong `keyEvent` codes (like '1' instead of "1" or VK_1) or having the default `getInputMap()` method instead of `getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_IN_FOCUSED_WINDOW);` . I seem to have dealt with all of those and yet the label still don't update when I'm pressing the keys .

My question : what's wrong ? am I supposed to have the labels focused instead of the whole panel ? wrong keycode ? I've tried a lot of supposed solutions and just can't get a break!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As far as I can see, the reason the labels do not update is just because you don't update them:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    p1Score += 1;
    p1ScoreLabel.setText(String.valueOf(p1Score));
}
```

And:

```
@Override
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
    p2Score += 1;
    p1ScoreLabel.setText(String.valueOf(p2Score));
}
```

Comment: Indeed -- they're not going to *magically* change unless there is code for them to change. 1+

Comment: oh! you're right, it works perfectly now. Somehow I thought that `p1ScoreLabel = new JLabel(String.valueOf(p1Score));` in the constructor would handle that. Thanks a lot

Comment: @SergiuBesliu Nope! It doesn't work like that. : ) It's only given the value at that instant.